# Determining the number of solutions to a system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm beginning to work through an elementary book on linear algebra and while most everything I've seen so far is pretty easy review, one thing has struck me. Given a system of linear equations, say

$4x+3y+17z=0$

$5x+4y+22z=0$

$4x+2y+19z=0$

it asks us to "state why each system of equations must have at least one solution. Then solve the system and determine if it has exactly one solution of an infinite number of solutions".

The first part struck me because while it may be easy to see when a system of equation will not have a solution its not usually real easy to tell when it will. After a period of time I'd rather not admit to taking, i finally realized that this system along will all the others (not listed) in the problem set were set equal to zero...so I guess the authors are just trying to get us to state the fact that $(0, 0, 0)$ is always a solution?...or is there other way to easily observe when a system of equations will have a solution that I've been missing.

Some of the other systems:

1) $12x+5y+z=0$

$12x+4y-z=0$

2) $2x+3y=0$

$4x+3y-z=0$

$8x+3y+3z=0$

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear systems where all results are $0$ are called homogeneous, and the author most likely just wants you to observe the well known fact that every homogeneous linear system has the trivial solution $(0,\dotsc,0)$.

In general there is no good trick to see if a homogeneous linear system has solutions beside the trivial one, or if a non-homogeneous linear system has any solutions at all. One has to do some calculations like applying Gauß or calculating the determinant to make further statements. (This does not mean that a system cannot be nice enough to directly see what’s going, but this very much depends on the given system.)